# Jquery UI- The overlay not resizing when dialog is resized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Using Jquery to Open a dialog (with modal:true), which contains a form. Now i am removing some elements from the form based on choices made by user on the form.This resizes the dialog but the overlay is not resized. A shadow is left behind.
Is there a way to re size the overlay when the dialog is resized?

below is some code

```
//fadeout() some components on page based on choices made by user.
        if(selectedVal == 1){
            $("#modify_task_window").fadeIn();
            $("#modify_tag_window").fadeIn();
            $("#task_help_text").fadeIn();
        }else{
            $("#modify_task_window").fadeOut();
            $("#modify_tag_window").fadeOut();
            $("#task_help_text").fadeOut();
```

Now after this `fadeOut()` the dialog is resized but the overlay is not resized. A shadow is left behind.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer.
I just set the opacity of the shadow to zero. This solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Trigger a window resize event. The overlay will resize with it.  $(window).trigger('resize')